# Do I have to pay for Google Endpoints?

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, quota

I'm thinking of using the Google Endpoint service to add some simple features on my Android app. Following a tutorial on Github (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloWorld) I managed to create a very simple servlet with basic code and that's all I need. But it's not clear if I'll have to pay at some point (30 days free trial?) or if I only have to pay to access to the whole platform.. Is a simple servlet on Google Endpoints completely free without restrictions?

Comment: I think you are talking about only app engine. This should help https://cloud.google.com/pricing/#app-engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on where you are hosting your servlet. If it e.g.  meets the constraints for Google App Engine's [free quota](https://cloud.google.com/pricing/#app-engine) you won't have to pay (as far as I know). I am in fact running such an application since quite a while now.